# Question on posing a rigged 3D character

Tags: rigging

I am very new to Blender and 3D animating and have an issue I hope you all can help with.  I have a rigged character that I imported from fuse.  I am trying to pose my character for an animation.  What I want, is for a plane that is placed below the characters feet to act as a solid floor when I am posing.  To elaborate, when I select the upper torso for posing and lower it, I want the feet to act on the plane as a solid ground so that the knees buckle naturally when I lower the torso, without even having to select the legs.  As it is now, if I lower the torso, all of the character, legs and all, just pass through the plane and remain straight.  Another character I downloaded had this feature, so that I didn't have to mess with the legs to get a natural squating movement, but I cannot reverse-engineer how that file had done it to apply the same to a diffrent character that I would like to use.  I am sure this is a basic question for all you pros, so hopefully someone can imagine what I'm describing and provide the solution.  Thank you all in advance for your time.

Comment: What you're thinking of is inverse kinematics. There are lots of tutorials on youtube for IK rigging.

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.